# Matplotlib animation not saving properly

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I'm working on a script that moves a vertical line along an x-axis, over a series of datapoints. The animation works fine with `plt.show` but I am having trouble outputting a movie file. Please be aware that I am very new to Python, though I've been playing around with it for a year or two. The script was created by combining the first script in [this tutorial](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/) with the script presented in the answer to [this previous stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942936/progress-line-in-matplotlib-graphs). The line will eventually be moving over a static data line chart, which I am presenting here as a diagonal line.

The movie file is output as having the correct length of time (1min, 10sec), but the line, which should move from the far left to the far right, 1-point per second, only moves a few pixels in the output video.

Any help you may be able to provide to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I'm running Python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Here is my reproducible code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import time

# Simulated background data
x = np.linspace(0,61,62)
y = np.linspace(0,6,62)

# Set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
max_height = 6  # max height of y-axis
n_pts = 61      # max length of x-axis

# Original location for progress line
y1 = [0, max_height]
x1 = [0, 0]

fig = plt.figure()          # Initialize figure
#ax = fig.add_subplot(111)  # Intialize axes
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, n_pts), ylim=(0, max_height))    # Set axes limits
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)                           # Initialize line

# draw the data to the 'background'
line1, = ax.plot(x, y, color='black')

# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    line.set_data(x1, y1)
    return line,

starttime=time.time()
mytimer=0
mytimer_ref=0

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    t = time.time() - starttime
    mytimer = t + mytimer_ref
    x1 = [mytimer,mytimer]
    line.set_data(x1, y1)
    return line,

# call the animator.  
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=61, interval=1000)

# save the animation as an mp4.  This requires ffmpeg or mencoder to be
# installed.  The extra_args ensure that the x264 codec is used, so that
# the video can be embedded in html5.  You may need to adjust this for
# your system: for more information, see
# http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/animation_api.html

writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg'](fps=1)

anim.save('demo.mp4',writer=writer,dpi=dpi)

plt.show()
```

**Edit** The following script creates the movie and saves it as an mp4. The problem now is that though there are 61 frames of animation, I can't get the movie to stop there. It proceeds to 100 frames every time. I know this question is a bit old now, but any help is greatly appreciated!

I have attempted to manually set the x-axis, which limits what is shown on the screen, but the animation continues beyond the shown axis nonetheless.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from time import time
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

max_height = 6  # max height of y-axis
n_pts = 62      # max length of x-axis

x = np.linspace(0,61,62)
y = np.linspace(0,6,62)

# New figure with white background
fig = plt.figure(facecolor = 'white')
ax = plt.axes(aspect=1) # Set axes limits

# Original location for progress line
y1 = [0, max_height]
x1 = [0, 0]

# initialize line
plt.plot(x, y) #plot background
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2) 

def update(frame):
    x1 = frame
    line.set_data(x1, y1)

    # Return the modified line
    return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=1000, blit=True)
anim.save('line.mp4', writer='ffmpeg')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Still no answer, but somehow, the `interval` option is ignored when the animation is saved. Oddly, the call to `animation.FuncAnimation` does not actually create the animation. If you include a variable that saves each `mytimer` value, and print this variable you only start seeing an output after your call to `anim.save` - but not before. However, the `anim.save` just calls your animation 61-times, but without obeying the `interval`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. This gives me a little something to work with and I'll update if it comes to anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your edited code, include two additional arguments in the call to [`animation.FuncAnimation`](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation):

1. `frames=25` (`25` chosen as an example) - set the max number of frames again
2. `repeat=False` - do not repeat the animation after the max number of frames

Combined, you get this command:

```
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=25,
                               interval=1000, blit=True, repeat=False)
```

This results in a animation which steps through 25 frames (in your case, moves the vertical line from `0` to `24` in one second intervals) - and stops there.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reminder! Edit: I think I hit upvote instead of accept. Thanks again. I ended up iterating on this quite a bit but this answer was pretty fundamental to my problem solving.