# Saving Animation in matplotlib of Progress Line

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, save

Objective: To save a plotted graph(x,y) with a moving a vertical line over the graph w.r.t to timer.

I've built a simple graph with a moving vertical progress line basically identical to this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942936/progress-line-in-matplotlib-graphs), but I now need to save it. I do not need the functionality to relocate the progress bar on-click, only to have the progress bar move along the data. I'm not sure where to call the save function because this code does not rely on FuncAnimation.

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import numpy

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

max_height = 100
n_pts = 100
y1 = [0, max_height]
x1 = [0, 0]
y = numpy.random.randn(n_pts) * max_height
x = numpy.arange(0, n_pts)

# draw the data
line1, = ax.plot(x, y, color='black')

# fix the limits of the plot
ax.set_ylim(0, max_height)
ax.set_xlim(0, n_pts)

# draw the plot so that we can capture the background and then use blitting
plt.show(block=False)

# get the canvas object
canvas = ax.figure.canvas
background = canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax.bbox)

# add the progress line.
# XXX consider using axvline
line, = ax.plot(x1, y1, color='r', animated=True) 

starttime=time.time()
mytimer=0
mytimer_ref=0

def update(canvas, line, ax):
    # revert the canvas to the state before any progress line was drawn
    canvas.restore_region(background)

    # compute the distance that the progress line has made (based on running time) 
    t = time.time() - starttime
    mytimer = t + mytimer_ref
    x1 = [mytimer,mytimer]
    # update the progress line with its new position
    line.set_xdata(x1)
    # draw the line, and blit the axes
    ax.draw_artist(line)
    canvas.blit(ax.bbox)

timer=fig.canvas.new_timer(interval=100)
args=[canvas,line,ax]
timer.add_callback(update,*args) # every 100ms it calls update function
timer.start()
plt.show()
```

Comment: One of the advantages of using `FuncAnimation` is that it allows to easily save an animation. If you are aware of that fact, it's not clear from the question why you chose not to use it. As it stands, the answer would simply be: Use `FuncAnimation`.

Comment: I agree that FuncAnimation is the best route. The problem is I am not sure how to use FuncAnimation in this manner.